# How to rotate single benzene ring with `chemfig`?

Tags: graphics, chemfig

In `chemfig`, creating a benzene ring results in the second atom being at the very bottom:

```
\chemfig{**6(A------)}
```

[image]

How do I get one of the benzene ring sides to be parallel to the horizontal? In other words, how to I rotate the ring 90° in any direction, without rotating the rest of the molecule (which I will add later)?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can use the following syntax to specify any angle  `\chemfig{[:90]A*6(------)}` (see p.17 of `chemfig` manual)

Comment: @AndreyL. You're the bestest. If you include your solution as an answer, I'll mark it as the accepted solution. God bless you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can rotate to any angle

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
    \chemfig{[:30]A**6(------)}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Source:
https://tug.ctan.org/macros/generic/chemfig/chemfig-en.pdf (at the bottom of page 17)